# Sum of n terms of a G.P. confusion in formulas

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

If we have to find the sum of n terms of a G.P. then we have two formulas for it (1) $a(1-r^n)/(1-r)$ and (2) $a(r^n-1)/(r-1)$. Now I know how the (1) has been derived but dont know about the (2)(is it obtained by multiplying denominator and numerator of (1) by -1?). I am also confused when two use them and why there exists 2 formulas for the same objective? pls explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your post and as Dr. Sonnhard Graubner has mentioned in his answer, you can get one expression from the other by multiplying by $-1$ on the numerator and denominator. Which one you use is just a matter of preference. In particular, when working with geometric series where $r > 1$, I would guess that people prefer to work with (2), since $r^n - 1$ and $r-1$ are positive quantities, so the resulting fraction is more aesthetic, but, for the same reason, (1) will tend to be used when $r < 1$.

Comment: yeah i totally get what you are saying but the book which im studying says when |r|<1 use (1) but when r<= -1 or r>1 use (2).... please explain me this

Comment: So I have only considered positive $r$ above, but the reasoning remains the same: reducing the number of minus signs you're likely to be dealing with. Sticking to the conventions given in the book ensures that you produce as few minus signs as possible, just to make the probability of a sign error lower. I can't stress enough though that it doesn't actually matter which formula you use, both will give you the right answer, because they are essentially the same formula. You're multiplying the fraction by $1 = \frac{-1}{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $(-1)$
$$\frac{a(r^n-1)(-1)}{(r-1)(-1)}$$